# Sqlalchemy connection don't see new rows in db

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have app with nginx+uwsgi+django+postgresql where i use sqlalchemy (psycopg2 dialect) for queries like

```
engine = create_engine(...)
engine.execute(select_statement)
```

And have separate script that write to db by cron job.
But sqlalchemy connection don't see new rows. 
Script write to db using django orm. I tried add transaction.commit() after writing tod b, but  it's not help.

Sqlalchemy see new rows only after restarting uwsgi processes (kill && start, touch-reload not help). 
I tried add pool_recycle=60 as param to create_engine, tested with different isolation levels (read uncomitted too), but not help too... I don't know how to fix this. Thanks for help.

PS. Tried connect using psycopg2 and all is correct, all rows are selected. Tried use sessions, autocommit, explicitly commit session ... none of this has helped.

Comment: commit before reading.

Comment: "explicitly commit session" - i tried commit before reading and after reading. anyway after committing before or after, next request should be with new data. but it's not.